# Date difference calculation in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have two fields of dates with name of from and to. What I want is to calculate their differences in next text box (named `diff`). I am not able to fetch date values in PHP whoever I am using below mentioned static value for date, it's showing me accurate results.

Here is my code:

```
<body>
From : <input type="date" name="from">
To : <input type="date" name="from">

<?php
    $datetime1 = new DateTime('2016-09-3');
    $datetime2 = new DateTime('2016-09-5');
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
?>

Diff : <input type="Text" name="diff" id="diff" value="<?php echo $interval->format('%R%a')+1;?>">
</body>
```

Comment: Do you need dynamic result (when user change a date, the Diff text box is automatically update), so you will need Javascript?

Comment: It doesn't work like that. PHP runs on the server. If you want to use PHP commands without leaving the page, you have to send data to the server using AJAX, then display the result.

Comment: Thanks for your help dear. i will try and incase of any issue i will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap these inputs to the form element, so your HTML will looks like:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    From : <input type="date" name="from">
    To : <input type="date" name="to">
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
```

Then in PHP just do this:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime($_POST['from']);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($_POST['to']);
```

Well, I know I haven't put any security about empty inputs or invalid data, but I hope this will lead you to your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
<form>
From: <input type="date" name="from">
To: <input type="date" name="to">
<input type="submit" name="calc">
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_GET['calc'])) {

    $from = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "from");
    $to = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "to");

    $datetime1 = new DateTime($from);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($to);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

    echo "Diff: " .  ($interval->format('%R%a') + 1);
}
?>
```

Comment: Chris G ... thanks for your help dear, it's working and i am sure this will work as per my requirement. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a other ways to get calculate time difference.

```
$seconds = strtotime($_POST['date2']) - strtotime($_POST['date1']);
```

By getting the seconds we can now get the difference in other date formats like hours, weeks etc.

```
$year   = floor($seconds / 31556926);
$months = floor($seconds / 2629743);
$week   = floor($seconds / 604800);
$day    = floor($seconds / 86400); 
$hours  = floor($seconds / 3600);
$mins   = floor(($seconds - ($hours*3600)) / 60); 
$secs   = floor($seconds % 60);
```

Comment: I believe the question is about getting the entered values to PHP, not the specifics of the date calculation.

Comment: but you have two filed and same name from  how to calculate ? i update my answer

Comment: The OP is trying to use PHP after the page has loaded and the user has entered the dates. It doesn't work that way though, the form has to be sent first (or AJAX). That's the crux here.